# Zoom view on rescaled bitmap

Tags: android, shader, zooming

I'm currently working on a multipoint cropping tool and I've been stuck for a few days now. So basically, this works like this:

1) take a large resolution photo with the device's camera 
2) put the resulting bitmap on the screen using a custom class(which extends ImageView)
3) draw handlers over the detected contours - these are later used for cropping the large bitmap.

[image: Screen shot]

I want to implement a circular zoom when dragging the corner handlers to allow for a better adjustment from the user. This is what I've done so far:

```
@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    originalBitmap = bm.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    shaderPaint = new Paint();

    shader = new BitmapShader(originalBitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
    shaderPaint.setShader(shader);

    shaderMatrix = new Matrix();
    ....
```

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    .......
    if (zooming) {
        shaderMatrix.reset();
        inverseMatrix.reset();
        if (getImageMatrix().invert(inverseMatrix)) {
            float[] pts = new float[2];

            pts[0] = currentMovedPoint.x;
            pts[1] = currentMovedPoint.y;
            inverseMatrix.mapPoints(pts);
            shaderMatrix.postTranslate(-pts[0], -pts[1]);           
            shaderMatrix.postScale(2f, 2f);

            shader.setLocalMatrix(shaderMatrix);
            canvas.drawCircle(zoomCenterX, zoomCenterY, zoomRadius, shaderPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(zoomCenterX - 20, zoomCenterY, zoomCenterX + 20, zoomCenterY, borderPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(zoomCenterX, zoomCenterY - 20, zoomCenterX, zoomCenterY + 20, borderPaint);
        }
    }
```

zoomCenterX and zoomCenterY are fixed points on the canvas. The problem is that the zoom view is not centered on the currentMovedPoint coordinates(it is offset by exactly zoomCenterX, zoomCenterY). If i set zoomCenterX and zoomCenterY to 0, the zoom view is correctly centered - but i cannot use that since only a quarter of zoom circle appears on the screen.

I have tried translating the shaderMatrix by zoomCenterX and zoomCenterY with no success(the zoom view is still not centered on the currently selected point).

Am I going about this the wrong way or is there something I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so posting the problem made me examine my algorithm once more. The problem was I needed to apply another translation to the shader matrix before attaching it to the shader.

So i added:

```
float[] centerPts = new float[2];
centerPts[0] = zoomCenterX;
centerPts[1] = zoomCenterY;
inverseMatrix.mapPoints(centerPts);
shaderMatrix.postTranslate(-centerPts[0], centerPts[1]);
```

after

```
 shaderMatrix.postScale(2f, 2f);
```